# Django Form-Model issue;

Tags: python, html, django

I am having trouble working with models and forms in Django. A little clarification and help will be highly appreciated!

I am really confused because I do not see the form in my html url page. I see everything else but not the form. I assume, I'm missing something.

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import TwitterContainer

class TwitterUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TwitterContainer
        fields = ["Twitter_API_key", "Twitter_API_key_secret", "Twitter_API_token", "Twitter_API_token_secret"]
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TwitterContainer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Twitter_API_key = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    Twitter_API_key_secret = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    Twitter_API_token = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    Twitter_API_token_secret = models.fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Twitter Container'
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import TwitterUpdateForm


@login_required
def twitter(request):
    tw = TwitterUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    
    if tw.is_valid():
        tw.save()
        messages.success(request, f'NICE!')
        return redirect ('home')
    else:
        tw = TwitterUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        
    context = {'tw': tw}
    
    return render(request, 'twitter_container/twitter_container.html', context=context)
```

And last but not least, this is my html file.

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        </div>
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Information</legend>
                {{ u_form|crispy }}
                {{ p_form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Oh, and my urls.py as well.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('twitter/', twitter_views.twitter, name='twitter'),
]
```

The issue, I'm facing is that I'm unable to display the form fields from the model to the html. I want to be able to import information into the fields and update it to the database.

Please, do not judge me hard, I am completely newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do `{{ u_form|crispy }}` and `{{ u_form|crispy }}` do? Are they supposed to render the form?

Comment: Well, yes but I didn't update them from a previous html and in this case, this was an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to add action attribute in your form tag to call the view function when form gets submitted.

It should be like this:

```
<form method="POST" action ="{% url 'twitter'  %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second thing that i found wrong in your html code is, why did you use u_form and p_form as a context variable? it should be 'tw' as per your view.

Try it out with above changes, it might help you out with your requirements.

Comment: Everything seems to be working right now but the changes are not being saved to the database for some reason. I tried to sync the db but nothing happen. Normally, those inputs should be associated into the db to the user that is logged now. I django-admin look like this - https://imgur.com/XOsoXom

Comment: just try to print all the things in shell i.e. request.user and whether form is valid or not, if you get the user right with if condition executed, then try to add random twittercontainer data from admin panel and check if it is being saved or not, if not then you need to check your database configuration.

Comment: I could update the data for a while but by adding the user as a tab in to the form. Basically, I can choose the user for which I like to update the form. Same as the one in the django-admin. When I remove the user field from the form, I'm receiving this error - https://imgur.com/PYktXK0. I searched a lot in the web but I'm really unable to find any reason, why my user.id is not being linked with the logged user. In other words, it only works if I add the user into the forms as a choice, otherwise, not.

Comment: You must create a migration, where you will specify default value for user, since you don't want it to be null. If null is not required, simply add null=True and create and run migration or you can change validation of user in your forms.py

Comment: Well, I'm confused now and I do not have any idea how I can proceed. I want the views.py to get the current instance of the user (the logged user).

this is my views.py
https://imgur.com/h9oU7bh

also I edited my model like this https://imgur.com/Qv0mk3m.

Comment: use foreign key instead of onetoone in user field, and to get current logged user, request.user should work fine

Comment: if you have found the answer and comments right to fulfill your requirements then please accept the answer.

Comment: I did not answer my question. I redo the migrations and reset the database. Updated everything so far but it is still not working. https://imgur.com/Va5jVDQ - This is the models and the views (using foreignkey this time). This is my html - https://imgur.com/9Uzd1P5. This is how it looks like in the django-admin - https://imgur.com/rTLBAhE (you choose user and update the data without issues). Also, here are like the containers look like - https://imgur.com/Omp1KCJ (with a signals, I'm automatically creating one for a new user). The issue is that the data is not updating into the database yet.